# Flutter keyboard : change bottom actions / options IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, keyboard, action

Is there a way in flutter to change these keyboard actions and put emoji on bottom ?

[image]

Here is my iMessage keyboard :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't (easily) alter the keyboard through Flutter.
You either have to catch the event that a keyboard will pop and display your keyboard custom widget.

Or Either, the user has to switch his keyboard beforehand.

Comment: Please see edits.  My phone keyboard is set in this configuration. why my app doesn't copy this config then ?